# Solidity decimal values

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I need put a minimum value of user can pay, and this value must be e.g 0.5 BNB.
But I don't know how I can do this.

```solidity
    uint comissionFee = 5; // 5 will represent 0,5
    uint256 minimunPay = comissionFee*100/1000;
```

But return 0

```solidity
  pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

  function payFees() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.5); // <-- not compatible with uint256
    (bool success,) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send money");
  }
```

Comment: [How can I represent decimal values in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-can-i-represent-decimal-values-in-solidity/2990)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In solidity `msg.value` is not represented as Ether but as Wei a smaller denomination of ether you can think of it as ether with 18 decimals. Example:
1 ether is `1000000000000000000` Wei. Note that this applies for most chains to my knowledge BSC is also based on an 18 decimal system so 0.5BNB would be `500000000000000000` Wei this way you can check decimal values like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

  function payFees() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 500000000000000000);
    (bool success,) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send money");
  }
```

Or:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

  function payFees() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.5 ether);
    (bool success,) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send money");
  }
```

You can also take a look at [this](https://eth-converter.com/) for a better demonstration of how this works.

Comment: Just a bit of correction BNB has 8 decimals and the smallest unit of BNB is Jager

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, there are no double numbers in solidity lang.

All calculations are done with whole numbers. To solve this issue, all tokens on Ethereum/Binance Chain consider some big decimal number as a threshold of double and ceil parts.

In ERC20 tokens this number is calculated based on the decimal field of the contract: `10^decimal`.

For the native token ETH/BNB, there is a fixed decimal equal to 18.
Your code could be fixed this way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

  function payFees() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.5 ether);
    (bool success,) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send money");
  }
```

OR

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

  function payFees() public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 5 * 10**17);
    (bool success,) = owner.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send money");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solidity works with integers. [Why are there no decimal numbers in Solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623122/why-are-there-no-decimal-numbers-in-solidity/72624594#72624594)

Uniswap created [FixedPoint](https://github.com/Uniswap/solidity-lib/blob/master/contracts/libraries/FixedPoint.sol). you can use this function:

```
function fraction(uint256 numerator, uint256 denominator) internal pure returns (uq112x112 memory) {
    require(denominator > 0, 'FixedPoint::fraction: division by zero');
    if (numerator == 0) return FixedPoint.uq112x112(0);

    if (numerator <= uint144(-1)) {
        uint256 result = (numerator << RESOLUTION) / denominator;
        require(result <= uint224(-1), 'FixedPoint::fraction: overflow');
        return uq112x112(uint224(result));
    } else {
        uint256 result = FullMath.mulDiv(numerator, Q112, denominator);
        require(result <= uint224(-1), 'FixedPoint::fraction: overflow');
        return uq112x112(uint224(result));
    }
}
```

in your solidity code:

```
 using FixedPoint for *;

 FixedPoint.fraction(numeratorValue,denominatorValue)
```