# Why are there no decimal numbers in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I know that there are no floats/doubles in Solidity but I am wondering *why?* I've googled it and all I can find are questions about how to deal with this lack.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason behind is `floating-point` operations calculated by various functions can produce different results in different runtime environments. Ethereum blockchain is deterministic which ensures that smart contracts always produce the same output for the same input.

Also for large size of transactions, a very little difference in rounding floating numbers will cause a big difference in finance

Comment: This is not correct; see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are some answers that "floating points are not deterministic".

This is not true. Floating point calculations can be made deterministic with standardised software implementation.

The reason why EVM does not have floating points is

- Lack of demand
- Trade-off for VM implementation complexity
- Developers not understanding the issue

For an implementation example

- [See e.g. discussion about using softfloat on EOS blockchain here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/issues/41)
- [See EOS float implementation](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/search?q=float)

Comment: Upvote as this correct. Also developers confusing floating point binary with fp decimal.

Answer (score 1):

See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/58751

> The obvious reason is that floats are, by nature, unpredictable, which would make the outcome of operations different over nodes. Which would lead to forks.

Also: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#fixed-point-numbers

Comment: This is not correct; see my answer.